# Strange behavior of Struts2 Type conversion for java.util.Date class

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, date, struts2

I am using struts2 Framework and Hibernate ORM

I am initializing one model class object by getting values from database.
There is one property named abc1 of data type java.util.Date in model class that is corresponding to one field named abc2 with data type DATETIME in database

There is no problem of getting value form database but it is coming different(appending extra characters).

For example -

In database if column abc2's value is 2007-11-13 11:24:00

then its value is coming as 2007-11-13 11:24:00.0 (**dot zero**) in abc1 variable of model class

I have debugged by code, it is showing following values for abc1 variable

[image]

fasttime is datetime in millisecons, but what is **cdate** and **nanos**?

Is it some encoding issue?

Comment: They're private fields - and thus *implementation details* that you shouldn't care about.

Comment: You can check openjdk source eg here : http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Date.java.html but as @JonSkeet pointed, they are implementation/vendor specific fields on which you can not rely or take care at all.

Comment: Why do you care if zero is being appended?

Comment: What kind of requirement is that? Anyway where do you get this string?

Comment: After getting value from database, for assurance, m printing its value. there it is showing. The problem is from where this extra 0 is coming

Comment: Still don't understand why the extra zero bothers you. Why this is the problem for you?

Comment: @AleksandrM I can change the format the date easily by using SimpleDateFormat, but my problem is from where this extra 0 is coming and why? BTW thank you very much, you are still trying to sort out my problem :)

Comment: So you need just **why**. The **why** is simple. Because `Timestamp#toString` method is defined in such way. The `.0` in your case are nanoseconds.

Answer (score 0):

This is a java.sql.Timestamp object that extends java.util.date

excerpt from the apidoc about cdate:

> If cdate is null, then fastTime indicates the time in millis. If
>   cdate.isNormalized() is true, then fastTime and cdate are in synch.
>   Otherwise, fastTime is ignored, and cdate indicates the time.

the nanos field is an extra addition to the millisecond based Date to make Timestamp more precise.

Answer (score 0):

For date formatting and styling,After you fetch the date from the database and before you print or send them you can format them in your preferred style and remove `the .0 (dot zero) from the string.`

[Simple Date Format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)